# Define constants in XML

Tags: xml

How do I define constants in a XML document, for example

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<City>
   <Name>Seattle</Name>
   <State>WA</State>
</City>

<City>
   <Name>Tacoma</Name>
   <State>WA</State>
</City>
```

How do I define a variable like "State=WA" and use it in the  element as the value?

Comment: You mean like `<City State='WA'>` ?

Comment: Sorry, I mean <State>$(StateOfWA)</State>

Answer (score 3):

Question is long ago but maybe someone else stumbles over this ... the following might be what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources [
   <!ENTITY state "WA">
]> 
<City>
   <Name>Seattle</Name>
   <State>&state;</State>
</City>

<City>
   <Name>Tacoma</Name>
   <State>&state;</State>
</City>
```

Comment: Yes!  I would never mean to disagree with Michael Kay, but I believe this is exactly what the OP was looking for.  It was certainly what I was looking for to put some constants in my XSD documents.  Thanks!

Comment: I am getting a org.xml.sax.SAXException: Line=2, Column=10: DOCTYPE is not allowed when "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" is set to "true"

Answer (score 2):

XML can represent structured information, you can enforce the structure of the markup by adding a DTD or XSD to your XML. But you can not represent constants or variables the way we use to think in programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use entity references like `&state;` where the expansion of the entity is defined in the DTD. More flexibly, you can use XInclude. But I would do this with XSLT. For example

```
 <xsl:stylesheet....>

 <xsl:param name="state"/>

 <xsl:template name="content">
  <City>
    <Name>Seattle</Name>
    <State><xsl:value-of select="$state"/></State>
  </City>

  <City>
    <Name>Tacoma</Name>
    <State><xsl:value-of select="$state"/></State>
  </City>
 </xsl:template>
```

Then you can invoke the stylesheet supplying the values of parameters.